# Obtaining Lawvere's "State categories and response functors"

Tags: ct.category-theory

I'm looking to get my hands on a (.pdf) copy of Lawvere's 1986 preprint *State categories and response functors*. If someone can post it and answer this question by offering a link, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Perhaps this paper is related to Lawvere's earlier, 1984 paper "State Categories, Closed Categories, and the Existence Semi-Continuous Entropy Functions", available online here: conservancy.umn.edu/handle/11299//4672 . Thanks to Thomas Holder for pointing this out. Still, I'm looking for the preprint discussed above "State categories and response functors"!

Comment: You could email him and ask, wlawvere@buffalo.edu , he is still alive and occasionally around the office!

Comment: This paper, along with many other hard-to-find Lawvere papers, can now be found in this GitHub repository maintained by Matt Earnshaw: https://github.com/mattearnshaw/lawvere

Answer (score 4):

A draft of Lawvere's paper was sent to me by Joachim Kock; it's the best I've found. I put it on my [webpage](http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/Lawvere--StateCategoriesResponseFunctors.pdf) for the convenience of others.